How can I prevent Views from rewriting HTML attributes with underscores in a Custom Text field?
In my Drupal 10 View, I have a Custom Text field with a <div> that looks like this:
<div class="owl-carousel init-carousel-owl owl-loaded owl-drag" data-items="1" data-items_lg="1" data-items_md="1" data-items_sm="1" data-items_xs="1" data-loop="1" data-speed="800" data-auto_play="0" data-auto_play_speed="900" data-auto_play_timeout="5000" data-auto_play_hover="0" data-navigation="1" data-rewind_nav="0" data-pagination="1" data-mouse_drag="0" data-touch_drag="0">

The View's output is rewriting some of the data- attributes by removing the data-xxx_ part. So, for example, this...
data-auto_play="0"

...becomes...
play="0"

It seems to only affect the data- attributes that have an underscore _ in their name. See the example above, but an attribute like data-pagination="1" would not be rewritten.
Why is this happening? And more importantly, how can I prevent it?

The Views Addons module seems to have solved this issue for me. After enabling, just add an Advanced Custom Text field to your view.
As an honorable mention, it looks like Views Unrestricted Custom Field module would have worked too, but it's got a scary warning on the page about not being covered by Drupal's security advisory policy.
